# Error in the document XML (2, 454) tryind to convert object to xml

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I´m trying get data from a Web Service using c# my procedure is convert the object to a XML like this

```
        private void btnLecturaBLur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the web service method
        recibodlxService service = new recibodlxService();

       // Convert the Xml from object
        string sXml = GetXMLFromObject(service.Controlrecibo());
```

this is how i get the XML from an Object..

```
public static string GetXMLFromObject(object o)
{
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter tw = null;
try
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
    tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    serializer.Serialize(tw, o);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle Exception Code
}
finally
{
    sw.Close();
    if (tw != null)
    {
        tw.Close();
    }
}
return sw.ToString();
```

}

and this is the XML from the web service

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP- 
  ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-
    ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
    xmlns:ns1="http://blutest.blulogistics.net/LFA/confirmRcv3.php" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-
    ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:ControlreciboResponse>
     <return SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns2:Map[6]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">OCN</key>
              <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                 <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">39147</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">codigo</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">17429</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Cantidad</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:int">12</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Estatus</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Disponible</value>
                       </item>
                    </value>
                 </item>
              </value>
           </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">OCN</key>
              <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                 <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">39147</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">codigo</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">32757</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Cantidad</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:int">13</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Estatus</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Disponible</value>
                       </item>
                    </value>
                 </item>
              </value>
           </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">OCN</key>
              <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                 <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">39147</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">codigo</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">48156</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Cantidad</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:int">6</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Estatus</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Disponible</value>
                       </item>
                    </value>
                 </item>
              </value>
           </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">OCN</key>
              <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                 <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">39147</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">codigo</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">52314</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Cantidad</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:int">7</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Estatus</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Disponible</value>
                       </item>
                    </value>
                 </item>
              </value>
           </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">OCN</key>
              <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                 <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">39147</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">codigo</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">55327</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Cantidad</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:int">10</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Estatus</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Disponible</value>
                       </item>
                    </value>
                 </item>
              </value>
           </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
           <item>
              <key xsi:type="xsd:string">OCN</key>
              <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                 <item>
                    <key xsi:type="xsd:int">39147</key>
                    <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">codigo</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">57813</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Cantidad</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:int">6</value>
                       </item>
                       <item>
                          <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Estatus</key>
                          <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Disponible</value>
                       </item>
                    </value>
                 </item>
              </value>
           </item>
        </item>
        </return>
    </ns1:ControlreciboResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

the error that is shows me is Error in the document XML (2, 454)

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You're trying to get data from a web service (which would be received as xml I assume) but you're calling serialize in your code. Are you trying to consume a web service and deserailze the result to an object? Or are you trying to send data to the web service by serializing an object?

Comment: I am **trying to get data from a web service and serialize** in my code